# Content Editor not "sticking"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-editor-web-part

I've got a blank we-part page. What I would like to do is hide the side-bar and possibly some of the upper menus - to give us more real estate for a report that will be embedded on the page.

I've added a Content Editor webpart with the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
     .ms-webpartPage-root {
         border-spacing: 0px !important;
     }
       .ms-webpartzone-cell {
         margin: 0px !important;
     }

     div#sideNavBox{display:none;}
     div#contentBox{margin:0 20px;}
</style>
```

When I press Apply the side-bar goes but then when I check the page in it reappears - then if I inspect the content editor the css has changed to the following:

```
<style>
.--root {
border-spacing:0px !important;
}

.--cell {
margin:0px !important;
}

 {
;
}

 {
margin:0 20px;
}
</style>
```

What is happening and how do I start going about hiding some of the menus ?

Any help appreciated, Jason

Comment: Do you face the same behavior with Script Editor Web Part? try to use it and feedback us with the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use your style in `Script Editor Web part` that gives me the desired result.

[image]

**[Output]**

After adding your style to `Script Editor Web part` then I **checked in** the page, everything works fine as shown below:

[image]